# Showing non-filtered results

Tags: excel, filter, vba

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$E$277").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Around 30-40"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

I currently have that code filtering a bunch of data. I only need to filter out one specific data but after recording, the vba gave me an extreme long code looking like I am checking off each specific data individually.

Is there a way for me to show the results on non-filtered value?

Can't show specific data, sorry.

Comment: Why don't you show us the full code, not just one line of it?

Comment: I tried to add a little more but that's all I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the recorder and selected a single item in a filter and got

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$33").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="abcd123"`

If you want the code for the items **not** selected by that filter then you would use

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$33").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>abcd123"`

Again this was produced by the macro recorder (although I dropped out the superfluous `Operator:=xlAnd` that it returned).  I simply selected `Text Filters` / `Does Not Equal` and entered the appropriate text.

Comment: Thanks !! Let's say the data I didn't want was specifically named "smith". Can I use the Criteria1:="<>Smith" ?

Comment: As far as I can see, yes.  There was nothing special about my text string of "a15" - it was just a made up string of letters / numbers.  (I just updated my answer to use something different, in case people mistook "a15" as meaning the cell at column 1 row 15.)